# How to stream icecast to Voice Channel with discord.js?

Tags: discord.js, bots, icecast

I have a radio station Icecast stream I wish to stream into a Discord Voice Channel with a discord.js bot.
It does not have Mute or Deafen icons, so that's set correct, but when I join I do not hear any audio.

The logs show it should be playing:
The audio player has started playing!

> <ref *1> AudioPlayer {
> _events: [Object: null prototype] { playing: [Function (anonymous)] },
> _eventsCount: 1,
> _maxListeners: undefined,
> _state: {
> status: 'playing',
> missedFrames: 0,
> playbackDuration: 100,
> resource: AudioResource {
> playStream: [OggDemuxer],
> edges: [Array],
> metadata: null,
> volume: 1,
> encoder: undefined,
> audioPlayer: [Circular *1],
> playbackDuration: 0,
> started: true,
> silencePaddingFrames: 5,
> silenceRemaining: -1,
> seek: 0
> },

It has the intents:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel],
});
```

Code for playing:

```js
// Bot joins voice channel
const player = createAudioPlayer();
const vcid = "VOICECHANNELID";
const guildid = "GUILDID";

client.on("ready",() => {
  const connection = VoiceDiscord.joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: vcid,
    guildId: guildid,
    adapterCreator: client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id == guildid).voiceAdapterCreator,
    selfDeaf: false,
    selfMute: false
  })
  const resource = createAudioResource(icecastStream, { inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary });
  resource.volume = 1;
  resource.seek = 0;
  player.play(resource);
  connection.subscribe(player);
});
```

Cheers!